# Adding a New Time to a Total Time

Tags: iphone, ios

What I am trying to do is add up the total time a player has stayed alive in a game. So, each time the game starts, I start a timer, and when the player dies, I terminate the timer. Every time this happens, I want this new time to be added up into a total time spent alive. This is my code:

```
int newTime = [newTimeLabel.text intValue];
int totalTime = [totalTimeLabel.text intValue];
int newTotalTime = newTime + totalTime;
totalTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total Time: %d",newTotalTime];
```

However, this the totalTimeLabel.text  keeps displaying only the new time, not the newTime added to the previous total time. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

An example of what I am trying to achieve:

> Trial 1:
>  newTime = 5 
> totalTime = 0 
> newTotalTime = 5 + 0 = 5
>
> Trial 2:
>  newTime = 7 
> totalTime = 5 
> newTotalTime = 7 + 5 = 12
>
> Trial 3:
>  newTime = 3 
> totalTime = 12 
> newTotalTime = 3 + 12 = 15

And so on...

Comment: Are you sure totalTime isn't zero?  That would explain why it would only display newTime.

Comment: Your example didn't go through but I get what you're saying :)  Yeah, if you still have a reference to the object that should work.  Hmm.  Try %i instead of %d?  Not sure it'll fix anything but I've always used %i for integers.

Comment: Wait...I see a problem. `int newTime = [newTime.text intValue];`  That should be `[newTimeLabel.text intValue]` right?  You've got two variables called `newTime` there.

Comment: My bad, that's what I have in my code, just miss-typed when I entered it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use UI elements (the **View** in **Model-View-Controller**) to store your application state/data (The **Model** in **Model-View-Controller**).

You should use some data variables of appropriate types to store your total accumulated time and your new time, and you should add these together and keep track of them completely independently of the UI (**View**).

If these values are transient (i.e. only need to be maintained for the life of the **Controller**) then it's ok (from a practical point of view, not a pure **MVC** one) to skip the whole **Model** part and just have the two variables in your **Controller**. Then whenever you update them you should also update the **View** by setting the labels. I recommend this approach for now.

However, if the user closes the app and comes back later, wouldn't it be nice if those values persisted? In which case, you should implement a persistent data-**Model**, and those values would be stored there so that you can retrieve them even after an app shutdown.

Search for information on the **MVC** design pattern, you'll find it really helpful in designing and implementing apps. It will help you avoid silly mistakes that will come back to bite you later on :)

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're saying, so as I add 1 value per second to the newTime, I should also be adding it to the total time and instead of reseting the totalTime after every game (Like I have been doing with the newTime), I could just keep it how it is. Also, the save the score, I have been using NSUserDefaults, but thanks for the tip on MVC, I will look into that.